# Как сгенерировать большое неотрицательное случайное число?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа, числа

Есть такая задача: сгенерировать случайное положительное натуральное число размер которого в битах равен, ну скажем 256. Подскажите как это сделать?
Пробовал таким образом:

```
BigInteger GetRandCount(int bits)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    byte[] count = new byte[bits / 8];
    random.NextBytes(count);
    return new BigInteger(count);
}
```

Но очень часто возвращаются отрицательные числа, а проверять на знак и генерить снова, мне кажется очень неэффективным по времени, или я ошибаюсь и стоит сделать именно так?

Comment: А зачем генерить снова? Почему бы не проверить полученное число на знак и вернуть его с `-`, если `< 0`?

Comment: Добавьте `Array.Resize(ref count, count.Length + 1);` перед `return`.

Comment: Какие требования к закону распределения? - это вопрос. Теперь если я правильно помню (сейчас я в метро и не могу проверить), у функции Rand () есть параметры, задающие интервал распределения.

Comment: @Михаил Муругов распределение окажется смещенным

Answer (score 2):

В двоичном представлении отрицательного числа установлен старший бит, просто сбросьте его:

```
// Не создавайте Random каждый раз, используйте один и тот же, это важно!
Random random = new Random();

BigInteger GetRandCount(int bits)
{
    byte[] count = new byte[bits / 8];
    random.NextBytes(count);
    count[count.Length - 1] &= 0b01111111; // Сбросили старший бит в 0
    return new BigInteger(count);
}
```

Либо, как подсказали в комментариях, просто верните противоположное число:

```
Random random = new Random();

BigInteger GetRandCount(int bits)
{
    byte[] count = new byte[bits / 8];
    random.NextBytes(count);
    BigInteger result = new BigInteger(count);
    return result > 0 ? result : -result;
}
```

---

На самом деле, правда, так как мы всегда сбрасываем старший бит, то у нас в итоге число получается на один бит короче. Т. е. если нам нужно **неотрицательное число указанной разрядности**, то нам надо запрашивать в массиве места на бит больше.

Если разрядность нашего числа всегда кратна 8, то всё просто — запрашиваем массив байтов на один длиннее и просто устанавливаем старший в 0:

```
Random random = new Random();

BigInteger GetRandCount(int bits)
{
    byte[] count = new byte[bits / 8 + 1];
    random.NextBytes(count);
    count[count.Length - 1] = 0;
    return new BigInteger(count);
}
```

Если разрядность может быть любой, не только кратной 8, то всё ещё немного усложняется, нам надо в старшем байте сбросить не все биты, а только часть из них:

```
Random random = new Random();

BigInteger GetRandCount(int bits)
{
    byte[] count = new byte[(bits + 8) / 8];
    random.NextBytes(count);
    byte mask = (byte)((1 << (bits % 8)) - 1);
    count[count.Length - 1] &= mask;
    return new BigInteger(count);
}
```

Comment: Лучше первый вариант - менять бит в байте. Потому что `BigInteger` иммутабельный тип и `-result` создаст новый экземпляр, а старый станет мусором - накладно в целом получается.